# How do I extract values from a width delimited table in Ansible?

Tags: parsing, ansible, jinja2, ansible-2.x, ansible-template

I'm trying to extract values from the result of an SQL command that is printed to stdout.

```
  first      second
  29494060   23004496
  29774383   22979864
```

I want to parse it into a data structure that looks something like this

```
[
  { first: 29494060, second: 23004496 },
  { first: 29774383, second: 22979864 }
]
```

So that I can access the values for each record like `{{ item.first }}` and `{{ item.second }}`.

I have been able to extract a single record by creating an object literal with values extracted with the `regex_replace` filter.

```
- set_fact:
    items: { first: "{{ item | regex_replace('\\s*?(\\d+)\\s*?(\\d+)', '\\1') }}", second: "{{ item | regex_replace('\\s*?(\\d+)\\s*?(\\d+)', '\\2') }}" }
  loop: '{{ command_out.stdout_lines }}'
```

This only keeps the result last line. I have not been able to create a list for each result. I have not been able to use list concatenation like `items: "{{ items | default([]) + [{…}] }}"` because of nested Jinja templates.

How do I extract a printed table of data into a list of objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create *keys*. For example

```
- set_fact:
    keys: "{{ command_out.stdout_lines[0].split() }}"
- debug:
    var: keys
```

gives

```
"keys": [
    "first", 
    "second"
]
```

then add the dictionaries, created by the filters [dict and zip](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_filters.html#zip-and-zip-longest-filters), to the list *sql_list*

```
- set_fact:
    sql_list: "{{ sql_list|default([]) +
                  [dict(keys|zip(item.split()))] }}"
  loop: "{{ command_out.stdout_lines[1:] }}"
- debug:
    var: sql_list
```

gives

```
"sql_list": [
    {
        "first": "29494060", 
        "second": "23004496"
    }, 
    {
        "first": "29774383", 
        "second": "22979864"
    }
]
```

---

The task simplified by [custom plugins](https://github.com/vbotka/ansible-plugins) gives the same result

```
- set_fact:
    sql_list: "{{ command_out.stdout_lines[1:]|
                  map('string_split')|
                  map('list_dict_zip_rev', keys)|
                  list }}"
```

```
$ cat filter_plugins/string_filters.py
def string_split(s, *i):
    if len(i) == 0:
        return s.split()
    elif len(i) == 1:
        return s.split(i[0])
    else:
        return s.split(i[0], i[1])

def list_dict_zip_rev(l,k):
    return dict((y,x) for x,y in  zip(l,k))

class FilterModule(object):
    ''' Ansible filters.'''

    def filters(self):
        return {
            'list_dict_zip_rev' : list_dict_zip_rev,
            'string_split' : string_split
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Vladimir! It's much more elegant than my colleague's solution that assigns each element as vars within the task. I've made one modification, by defining `vars: keys: […]` within the `set_fact` task. I'll accept after the customary 24 hours.